# Workflow for developing an e-commerce website with Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I need to develop a e-commerce type website with some typical modifications in it.

I want to develop the front-end by myself and I need some extra functionality it, it will be something like a printing service so maybe I will need a plugin that will allow user to upload images with the corresponding type of material used.

I decided to use a CMS because it will help me in the long run managing things and keeping everything safe.

I am proficient in the languages that are associated with these like PHP, Mysql, HTML, CSS etc. But know a little about WordPress or how it can be modified or what is the workflow for developing a e-commerce site with WordPress and woo-Commerce.

I need to design a front-end for it and some specific functionalities. Where should I start? What should I learn first?

Comment: you have the tag `woocommerce` start from there also check http://wp-types.com, they have some nice plugins for these functionalities

Comment: You should start with research efforts over specialized literature and tutorial sites. When you start coding and face issues, you come to Stack Overflow and ask a proper question for help.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit Stackoverflow.  Make a sample wordpress website first (using a free template), add the woocommerce plugin.  Play with it.    Learn how to create a child theme (takes 20 minutes or less)   Have some fun.  Then you won't even need to ask your question here.

Comment: Take a look at [the Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), you might find better help than you would here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a great community with free tutorials over the web.

Download woo-Commerce [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/).

You can find a decent beginner overview [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_mt-c_l36U).

You can find another one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8Op_sxowgI) which is more extensive, you can find part 2 to this one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_dpFMj9J40).

To make your own modifications to the code simply go to `/wp-content/plugins` and locate the w00-Commerce folder. You will most likely have to do these updates through ftp.

You should now be able to edit the php files associated with your woo-Commerce plugin for more customization.

You can expect your site to look something like this before modifications:
[image]

Hope this helps.

--lillypad